# Mysql returned Array with Keys and Tabelle-Names - delete Keys

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySQL table, where I run a query with left join:

```
  $db = $db->first("SELECT * FROM devices LEFT JOIN customer ON devices.customerid = customer.customerid WHERE devices.hash = '".$hash."' OR devices.deviceid = '".$hash."'");
```

**With this function:**

```
    //Select Datenbankanfrage, erste Zeile
function first($query, $restype=0) {
    $this->querystring = $query;

    if ( $restype==1 ) $restype=MYSQLI_ASSOC;
    else $restype=MYSQLI_BOTH;

    $result = $this->query($query); //Query
    if ( !$result ) return false;

    $row = $result->fetch_array($restype);
    $result->free();

    return $row;
}
```

But I recieve an `array` with keys as response:

```
1 => Maxii
Name => Maxii
2 => Streetfromthe
Street => Streetfromthe
```

How can I disable the keys (1,2) or how can I delete this in the array?

Here is a Nopaste from the full array returned:
https://nopaste.xyz/?23ccf318bbfc93fb#Oes85/9Z8+Kookk2nTLmbtObjaL8mD2aitPPrHV3v9w=

Comment: It looks like the link to your Paste is incomplete.

Comment: What do you pass to the function `first` because the second argument `$restype` decides if you should fetch associated array or both associated array and numerically indexed array. It may seem like you pass something else than 1 for this argument.

Comment: Thanks, thats work! Haha. Resttype = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from $restype, your second argument. It is zero by default which would use MYSQLI_BOTH, which returns fields by both index and names. You certainly want an associative array (MYSQLI_ASSOC), passing $restype to 1.

The lines that are responsible for changing the restype are:

```
if ( $restype==1 ) $restype=MYSQLI_ASSOC;
    else $restype=MYSQLI_BOTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace with `$result->fetch_array` with `$result->fetch_assoc`

EDIT: In your case, leave it at fetch_array and use the function you have.
Invoke it with `first($sql, 1);`

Comment: I have try that, then i become a Error.

Comment: @Burhan It would help if you posted the error message then.

Comment: That's because this alias, has a 2nd parameters.Leave it at `fetch_array`, but pass an extra paremeter to the first function, 1); SO it will only ASSOC only. AS it's stated in your code. Updated Answer